# RegisterHandler fires twice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When using the RegisterHandler I the associated function is executed twice. The message is only send once (I check at server). When the message comes in there is nothing for 10 seconds (due to sleep function I think) and then the ui thing I want to load appears twice. Anyone an idea why? Thanks in advance!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Client : NetworkManager 
{

    void Start()
    {

        NetworkClient client = new NetworkClient();

        client.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, askForName);
        Debug.Log("Registering server callbacks");
        client.Connect("", 7777);
    }

    void askForName(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {  
        GameObject UIdata = Resources.Load("Canvas") as GameObject;
        Instantiate(UIdata);
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are 100% sure that the server is only sending one message. This code you posted seems fine to me, there must be some other code/logic in the client causing this. Can you try disabling the client-server communication in the client and test that the behaviour happens correctly with a simple function call?